# twilio ip messaging in several browser tabs

Tags: php, angularjs, twilio

I'm trying to implement Twilio ip messaging. I've got a problem - when another tab with the chat is opened, chat stops recieving any messages in original browser tab. How can be this problem handled?

Comment: I've found a workaround, but thinking it is a bad idea. While generating token add a timestamp to endpointId like - $endpointId = $params['appName'] . ':' . $identity . ':' . $deviceId . time();

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do with the fact that your `endpoint_id` value is the same for all the endpoints. This causes the problem that IP Messaging cannot disambiguate the endpoints (subscribed and connected) to send the message (and other) events to.

This guide describes how to generate `endpoint_id` values, and why it is important: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/identity

An excerpt highlighting the specific area to focus on:

> About Endpoint IDs
>
> An "endpoint" in IP messaging is a unique app, device, and user
>   combination that can receive a message.
>
> For example, "alice@example.com" using "SquareChat" on her iPhone is a
>   different message delivery destination  (endpoint) than
>   "alice@example.com" using "SquareChat" on her Kindle Fire tablet.
>
> The endpoint ID you generate on the server - while it can be a string
>   in any format you want - should integrate at least these three
>   dimensions.
>
> Once your client receives an Access Token from your server, you can
>   initialize the Twilio IP Messaging SDK and start sending and receiving
>   messages.

Please note that if the same user logs in from 3 different endpoints - they should all have the same `identity` - but each of the endpoints should have a different `endpoint_id` - where the identity portion of the `endpoint_id` would be the same, but the other elements (application and device ids) should be different.